# What are the consequences of an expired digital signature of a C# assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, digital-signature, x509certificate

When you look at the "Digital Signatures" tab of a C# assembly in using the "Properties" menu in Windows, it shows the timestamp on which the assembly was digitally signed.

While the certificate expiry date is not shown on this menu, it can be checked this way using reflection:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("C:\xyz.dll");
var signingCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromSignedFile(assembly.Location);
var expiryDate = signingCertificate.NotAfter;
```

I read an article on difference between assembly strong naming and digital signatures but I still couldnt figure out what's the consequence of an expired certificate?

What happens if `DateTime.Today.Date > expiryDate.Date`?

Comment: Depends if the code is also timestamped while signing. If it is so code will be still trustable even if the certificate is expired

Comment: @Eldar How to check if the code is timestamped? What if the code is not timestamped?

Comment: [this](https://knowledge.digicert.com/general-information/code-signing-certificate-faqs#:~:text=Code%20Signing%20certificates%20are%20valid,when%20you%20purchase%20the%20certificate) might help.